# How to fix Time Out error 504 when calling www.googleapis.com:443 from lambda function (django)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway, google-signin

I am setting up a backend (django) and frontend (react) application. Here I am trying to implement google sign in through google-auth pypi package. So the front end calls the google sign in -> gets the token and passes it to a backend endpoint that receives the token and passes it to id_token.verify_oauth2_token() to get the details (name, username email etc).

Issue is that it works on my localhost well. Once I deploy the django package to lambda using Zappa, the HTTPS connection (1): www.googleapis.com:443 is timing out.

1. Upgraded the google-auth package
2. added domain to google api credentials
3. Passing the google client ID to make the call

Suspecting that there might be something on the AWS side that isn't allowing it to make an external get request. Not sure where to find this.

class GoogleSignIn(APIView):

```
permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    # upon signing in using google sign in, the front end calls /users/google-sign-in, which calls this method. It passes a OneTime googleUserId
    # this methods verifies the one time googleUserId with google to make sure that the signed in user is for our platform.
    # On successful verification, the google side will reply with a 200 response as well as additional information about the user.
    try:
        google_one_time_id = request.data['googleUserId']
        idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(
            google_one_time_id, requests.Request(), CLIENT_ID)
        if idinfo['iss'] not in ['accounts.google.com', 'https://accounts.google.com']:
            raise ValueError('Wrong issuer.')
```

Expected result is is a 200 response

Comment: Are you deploying the Lambda function into a VPC?

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lambda functions are authorized to make connections to external endpoints.  If your function is deployed into a VPC, the VPC must be configured for internet access (public subnet with an Internet Gateway attached or private subnet with a NAT gateway, you can read more details here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html)

AWS Lambda timeout after 3 secs by default, if your call needs more time, you can change this value in the lambda console or using the CLI (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/resource-model.html)

Your question needs to clarify if the 504 (TimeOut) is returned by the Lambda function invocation or the `id_token.verify_oauth2_token()` call, in which case the Lambda timeout is not the problem here.

Comment: I can confirm that the VPC is configured with subnets that have internet gateway access already. The security groups have outbound rules to destinationes 0.0.0.0/0. Thanks for responding. I am not sure where exactly this is getting blocked.  how do I see whether its lambda function or id.token?

Comment: I would add a try catch + print statement in your python code to check wether the error is generated by python runtime or lambda runtime

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and was able to solve it by doing these steps:

1. Create a subnet under the VPC your Lambda function has access.
   [image: create-subnet]
2. Create a NAT Gateway and add it to your subnet.
   [image]
3. Edit route table association in your subnet by adding Destination: 0.0.0.0/0 and Target: nat-xxxxxx.

You can read more about how to set up a NAT gateway here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/nat-gateway-vpc-private-subnet/

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with timed out lambdas today as well and it took me quite some time to realize that in my case it was lack of memory that caused the issues.

I already had a timeout of 1 minute, but my lambdas simply timed out. In `CloudWatch` or in `Lambdas` under `Monitor` tab you can see how much RAM you have allocated to a function and how much it actually uses.
When you see that you use the same amount you have allocated, you should give more memory to your functions.

In my case, I increased RAM from 128MB to 384MB and now everything works :)